# If I learn java how easy will it be to pick up actionscript?

Tags: java, actionscript-3

Should I learn Java first and then pick up actionscript latter (to build flash apps)? I guess I am asking if Java is a "real" language that will be a great base, and is actionscript more of a closed language within flash only.

I have played a little with each, but lately I have been putting all my time into Java.

Thanks!

Comment: Java's 'world' is massive compared to actionscript's 'world'. You will learn a lot more through Java, and unless you become fanatical about what a programming language should be like, it should be easy peasy to accept the different between java and actionscript and enjoy the many similarities which should make your life easier. I come from a visual/artsy background, so flash made more sense for me and eventually picked up actionscript and at some point started learning Java too, but from my experience, if you're a technical person, start with java, then learn actionscript + flex framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java is a great language to learn, and I highly recommend it, but since ActionScript is based on ECMAScript, its syntax is about all they have in common. They're really totally different languages, and you use them in very different ways.

One of the biggest differences is that ECMAScript uses prototypal inheritance. Java was my first language, and I had to spend a week or two to learn how to effectively leverage the unique features in ECMAScript-based languages instead of trying to do things the same way I would in Java.

That being said, I have always found that the more I learn about other languages and paradigms, the better my code is in **all** languages!

Comment: i believe the similarities between Java and AIR are close enough to say they are not used in different ways.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 - I have to disagree. The languages themselves differ on a pretty fundamental level. For example, it's impossible to use functional techniques effectively in Java. The functional aspect of ECMAScript is one of my favorite parts of a very hard-to-love language.

Comment: Also, one of the differences I have felt over is that Java is very sequence driven; if I make a web page request, I can have way to get the response in the next line. On the other hand, in AS3 almost all the code is cpu intensive. Event driven paradigm is inherent to as3

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn ActionScript, learn ActionScript.

If you want to learn Java, learn Java.

If you want to learn Java and ActionScript, learn Java and ActionScript.

One is not a prerequisite to the other. Both are handy to know.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely be easier. Why learn java then actionscript rather than just actionscript?

Kinda like learning to drive a stick before you learn to drive an automatic.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great illustration.

Answer (score 0):

They are both object oriented and actionscript is a lot easier than Java